# Why $\pi$ is not Constructible with Circumference Length

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

If we use a compass to draw a circle with a diameter of length 1, then the circumference is $\pi$. From the definition given here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number), it seems to me $\pi$ is a constructible length, which is definitely not the right conclusion. So where have I gone wrong?

Comment: "line segment" there means *straight* line segment.